# How to pass the parameter to filter the local json data in angular http get?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular7, http-get

I am setting parameter to get data,but params not working i am getting entire values as arrays. how to filter the data while getting. Here is how i am setting parameter to my service.ts file

```
   getinfojson(): Observable<IProduct[]> {

     let params = new HttpParams().set('projectname', "Sasi");

  this._http.get(this._producturl,{params : params}).subscribe( (res:Response)=>{
this.data = <IProduct[]> res.json();
console.log(this.data);
    })
```

i am getting all values from json as products array like below screebshot

[image]

but i need to get the details based on projectmanger name. How can i achieve this.

AND My product json file

```
{
    "product": [
        {
        "projectname":"Sasi",
        "Managername":"Shiva"
        },
        {
            "projectname":"Sasikala",
            "Managername":"Dhivya"
            },
            {
                "projectname":"SasiDhivya",
                "Managername":"Visu"
                }
    ]
}
```

For ur reference below is my imports of service ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { IProduct } from './product';
  import { Http , Response, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpParams, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable,of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'

})
export class ApiserviceService {
  data:any;
  ifb:any;
  private _producturl='../../assets/product.json';
   constructor(private _http: Http){}

   getinfojson(): Observable<IProduct[]> {

     let params = new HttpParams().set('projectname', "Sasi");

  this._http.get(this._producturl,{params : params}).subscribe( (res:Response)=>{
this.data = <IProduct[]> res.json();
console.log(this.data);
    })
    return this.data;

     }
```

Comment: Fix your server?

Comment: @Arif He is using mock data, which makes it a bit confusing.

Comment: i am not using any server just i want to read and write to my local json data

Comment: You should at least use https://github.com/typicode/json-server to easily read/write to your json

Comment: If you are fetching the data from local json file, then you have to manually filter once `http.get()` returns all the records. Alternatively you can have a look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-in-memory-web-api which facilitates the CRUD operations

Comment: @Arif, is json-server third party? or is this related to angular

Comment: It is not related to angular. It basically creates a rest api for your json file

Comment: i know with http only we cannot post in local json.. but we can get right?

Comment: is there any idea why my code not working? it does not have support or any syntax issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpParams class help to add request parameters to the REST API in wont filter the response instead u can use pipe and map to filter the data
ex:

```
 this._http.get(this._producturl,{params : params}).pipe(map((response) => {
    response = response.filter((data) => data.projectname === "Sasi" );
    return response;
})).subscribe( (res:Response)=>{
    this.data = <IProduct[]> res.json();
    console.log(this.data);
})
```

Comment: but map is not defined for me

Comment: import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import it from rxjs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want projectname to be the input and a `IProduct` to be the output here is what you need to do.

```
  this._http.get(this._producturl,{params : params})
    .pipe( 
       map( res => res.json() ),
       filter( res => res.product !== null ),
       map( res => {
          const matchingProduct = res.product.find( product => product. projectname === "Sasi");
          return matchingProduct;
       })
    )
    .subscribe( (matchingProduct)=>{
        this.data = matchingProduct;
        console.log(this.data);
    });
```

I also don't think you are using rxjs right when you take data out of streams, just save the entire stream on the `ApiserviceService` class

```
this.data$ = this._http.get(this._producturl,{params : params})
  .pipe( 
    map( res => res.json() ),
    filter( res => res.product !== null ),
    map( res => {
     const matchingProduct = res.product.find( product => product. projectname === "Sasi");
     return matchingProduct;
    })
  );
```

If you need to render `data$` just use the `async` pipe. If you need it in a different method, make a promise out of it and await it.

```
async methodThatNeedsProduct() {
   const product = await this.data$.pipe(take(1)).toPromise()
   // product is not available here
}
```